# nuget referencing c++ headers

Tags: c++, boost, nuget, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to write a C++ program which makes uses of Boost and other packages. So I installed the package `boost.1.59.0.0` using nuget.

The packages are indeed downloaded, but the project settings for additional include directories and additional library directories are still empty. Aren't those settings supposed to be updated by NuGet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings are updated but you will not see it in UI. Your project file is updated with references on Boost NuGet targets file "packages\boost\1.59.0.0\build\native\boost.targets". The targets file contains all required changes/settings to your project to work with Boost 1.59 headers.